# Backup Windows Server 2008 FTP e Cloud

Tags: windows, ftp, backup, cloud

Preciso gerar backups diários em um servidor windows server 2008 R2, os backups são de diversas pastas e aplicações instaladas neste servidor, o windows server possui ferramenta pra isso, alguma ferramenta do propio sistema?

Tenho pouca experiência com o so em questão, minha area na verdade e desenvolvimento.

Os backups precisam ser feitos para FTP e em um cloud da vida tipo dropbox e google drive.

Estive olhando algumas ferramentas de terceiros e não vi nada que se encaixe com o que preciso "custo/beneficio", estou pensando até mesmo em desenvolver eu mesmo a ferramenta.

Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Teste o Cobian Backup, talvez lhe sirva.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o robocopy do próprio Windows para otimizar seus backups de acordo com suas necessidades.

Documentação Robocopy - https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/cc733145(v=ws.10).aspx

E pode utilizar com cloud por exemplo o Google Drive, utilizando a sintaxe do tipo:

```
    robocopy "\\Diretório\" "\\GoogleDrive\dir" /copyall /sec /mir /r:1 /w:1
```

Comment: Interessante esse robocopy.. Me parece a melhor opção...